# Deploy Subnets into different availability zones using Ansible in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, subnet, vpc

I am Working on putting subnets into different availability zones in AWS with the help of ansible. I want to put subnet1 into us-east-1a, then subnet2 into us-east-1b and so on. Currently I can only be able to put servers onto us-east-1a only. Here is the ansible scripts.

```
---
- name: Create AWS VPC and Subnets
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
      region: us-east-1
      prefix: mahela_ansible
      az1: us-east-1a
      az2: us-east-1b
      az3: us-east-1c
 tasks:
 - name: Create VPC
   local_action:
     module: ec2_vpc
     region: "{{ region }}"
     cidr_block: 10.123.0.0/16
     resource_tags: '{"Name":"{{ prefix }}"}'
     subnets:
      - name: Cassandra Subnet
        cidr: 10.123.0.0/24
        az: "{{ az1 }}"
        resource_tags: '{"Name":"{{ prefix }}_cassandra"}'

      - name: MongoDB Subnet
        cidr: 10.123.1.0/24
        az: "{{ az2 }}"
        resource_tags: '{"Name":"{{ prefix }}_Mongodb"}'

      - name: Elastic Search
        cidr: 10.123.2.0/24
        az: "{{ az3 }}"
        resource_tags: '{"Name":"{{ prefix }}_elasticsearch"}'
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got in the question? At a glance that looks like it should work fine. Are you saying that playbook is building all 3 subnets in us-east-1a?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR : Yes.. Playbook is not going to separate different subnets into different availability zones. According to script it should work perfect, but it did not happen.

Comment: I think when I try to run on my AWS account, it runs successfully. My company has several servers running on various availability zones and that may be stopping it from creating new subnets for various AZs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example might help you.

`roles/vpc/defaults/main.yml` file look like this:

```
---
# Variables that can provide as extra vars
VPC_NAME: test
VPC_REGION: us-east-1 # N.Virginia
VPC_CIDR: "172.25.0.0/16"
VPC_CLASS_DEFAULT: "172.25"

# Variables for VPC
vpc_name: "{{ VPC_NAME }}"
vpc_region: "{{ VPC_REGION }}"
vpc_cidr_block: "{{ VPC_CIDR }}"
public_cidr_1: "{{ VPC_CLASS_DEFAULT }}.10.0/24"
public_az_1: "{{ vpc_region }}a"
public_cidr_2: "{{ VPC_CLASS_DEFAULT }}.20.0/24"
public_az_2: "{{ vpc_region }}b"
private_cidr_1: "{{ VPC_CLASS_DEFAULT }}.30.0/24"
private_az_1: "{{ vpc_region }}a"
private_cidr_2: "{{ VPC_CLASS_DEFAULT }}.40.0/24"
private_az_2: "{{ vpc_region }}b"

# Please don't change the variables below, until you know what you are doing
#
# Subnets Defination for VPC
vpc_subnets:
  - cidr: "{{ public_cidr_1 }}" # Public Subnet-1
    az: "{{ public_az_1 }}"
    resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}-{{ public_az_1 }}-public_subnet-1", "Type":"Public", "Alias":"Public_Subnet_1" }
  - cidr: "{{ public_cidr_2 }}" # Public Subnet-2
    az: "{{ public_az_2 }}"
    resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}-{{ public_az_2 }}-public-subnet-2", "Type":"Public", "Alias":"Public_Subnet_2" }
  - cidr: "{{ private_cidr_1 }}" # Private Subnet-1
    az: "{{ private_az_1 }}"
    resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}-{{ private_az_1 }}-private-subnet-1", "Type":"Private", "Alias":"Private_Subnet_1" }
  - cidr: "{{ private_cidr_2 }}" # Private Subnet-2
    az: "{{ private_az_2 }}"
    resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}-{{ private_az_2 }}-private-subnet-2", "Type":"Private", "Alias":"Private_Subnet_2" }
```

Then `roles/vpc/tasks/main.yml` file will be like this:

```
---
- name: Creating an AWS VPC inside mentioned Region
  ec2_vpc:
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    state:  present
    cidr_block: "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"
    resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}-vpc", "Environment":"{{ ENVIRONMENT }}" }
    subnets: "{{ vpc_subnets }}" 
    internet_gateway: yes
  register: vpc

- name: Tag the Internet Gateway
  ec2_tag:
    resource: "{{ vpc.igw_id }}"
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    state: present
    tags:
      Name: "{{ vpc_name }}-igw"
  register: igw

- name: Set up Public Subnets Route Table
  ec2_vpc_route_table:
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc.vpc_id }}"
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    state: present
    tags:
      Name: "Public-RT-for-{{ vpc_name }}-vpc"
    subnets:
      "{{ vpc.subnets | get_public_subnets_ids('Type','Public') }}"
    routes:
      - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
        gateway_id: "{{ vpc.igw_id }}"
  register: public_rt
```

For complete reference, take a look at this [github repo](https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-aws-roles).

Hope it help you or others.